# wkhtmltopdf not generating pdf files

Tags: php, pdf, wkhtmltopdf

I want to convert html files to pdf file. I have installed wkhtmltopdf in my pc .I have the following code to convert html file to pdf file .

```
$data = '<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quod laboriosam atque, consequuntur beatae fugiat in incidunt perspiciatis dolorem ipsum nam itaque animi nobis quam illum dolore. Nam nostrum maiores, ipsa.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsa vero veniam sed ullam commodi! Accusantium, officia vitae, adipisci mollitia, blanditiis voluptates accusamus nam atque repellendus laborum, ullam vel eligendi esse?</p>
</body>
</html>';

file_put_contents('test.html', $data);

$html_file_url = 'http://localhost/document-editor/test.html'; // html file 
$pdf_file_url = 'C:\\test.pdf'; // pdf file 

//$cmd = "C:/Program Files/wkhtmltopdf/bin/wkhtmltopdf http://localhost/";//$html_file_url $pdf_file_url";// command 
$cmd = "c:\Program Files\wkhtmltopdf\bin\wkhtmltopdf $html_file_url $pdf_file_url";// command 
//c:\Program Files\wkhtmltopdf\bin\wkhtmltopdf
exec($cmd);
```

But the pdf files is not generated . Where is the problem ? Please help me .

Comment: Does the command in `$cmd` work in the Windows command prompt? Try `echo $cmd` to get and test the command. Is `http://localhost/document-editor/test.html` accessible in a normal browser on your PC? Are you sure your PHP script is run with the correct permission to write in `C:\test.pdf`